# Kendo images don't display on PDF?

Tags: image, pdf, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, html-to-pdf

I am using Kendo UI editor and my image html is look like:
img alt="" src="http://mywebsite.com//ImageBrowser/Image?path=lion.png"

When I open this on browser it displays the image, but when I try to convert it to PDF, It doesn't display the image. Image src = actually is MVC controller/action. Is this the reason Winnovative converter to not be able to find the image, because src is not direct image path but uses MVC? Is there any workaround on this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the image links at runtime? If you can do that then I would suggest that you download all images to a temp folder configured to handle static content and point your references there. This is probably an authorization issue.